# Cross-platform alternative to Find My Friends

Tags: android, iphone-app, geo-location

My wife and I travel a lot and we've been using Find My Friends on iPhone to make sure we both get home safely. Today I jumped ship to Android and of course, we lost this native functionality.

Are there any cross-platform alternatives to Find My Friends?

Ideally I would be looking for simple look me up functionality, but the following **optional** features would be nice as well:

- Geofencing (get an alert when my wife gets home)
- Ability to temporarily suspend access
- Share location on demand (via SMS or the like)

Comment: Related: [Phone locator app for android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1712/185) (though not specifically cross-platform). Starting point until answers arrive: [List of location sharing apps for Android](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=126) (though I cannot tell which of those are cross-platform).

Comment: @Izzy: Do you have a suggestion for a "domain" tag for this question? (it currently only has tags for the required OS, but not what kind of software is needed / what the software is about)

Comment: @unor something along the lines of `geo-location`?

Comment: Hint: if you don't find one, stop thinking iOs/Android and start thinking browser