# Open source app for people to find each other via GPS

Tags: android, open-source, gps

I often loose time when meeting my friend in new places, because it is hard to pinpoint a particular meeting place:

> I am at the bus stop!
>   Me too!
>   But I can't see you!?
>   etc for 5 minutes

Is there an app that both of us could run when we want to find each other?
It could probably use the GPS and possibly some other tricks.

Requirements:

- Android
- Open source (I don't trust proprietary apps with my location)
- Shows me the distance that separates me from my friend, and the direction
- My friend also sees the same thing towards me

Bonus:

- Show both our positions on a map in real time, ideally using local OsmAnd maps rather than downloading maps via the network
- Insert bookmarks, for instance *"Tomorrow's picnic: we will sit here"*
- Share a bookmark or your location with several friends

Comment: Hi Nicolas, did you miss [Phone locator app for android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1712/185) – or how's your question different? ;)

Comment: @Izzy: Two main differences: 1) I need open source 2) That asker wants a map, but for me it is only a bonus.

Comment: It's going to be very approximate, especially if you are indoors & have to rely on location by cell tower, when you don't have a clear line of sight to overhead GPS satellites. Not much better than "I'm at the bus station", alas.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052517/how-is-location-accuracy-measured-in-android

Answer (score 1):

It seems too obvious, but did you look at [OsmAnd Maps & Navigation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand&hl=en) ?

It's Android, It's Open Street maps, it's free, and its many features include "Share your location so that your friends can find you".

The missing feature is sharing a bookmark (perhaps this can be done with Point Of Interest?). It does say "Save your most important places as Favorites", but I am unsure if you can share them (perhaps suggest it as a feature to the author?).

Comment: Unfortunately, OsmAnd's share feature are not as convenient as having a real time map showing both of our position.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for both Android and iOS called [Approach Me](http://approachme.net).  What does is it displays the distance and direction of the person you're looking for.  It uses a radar interface instead of a map so it's also good for places like parking lots or parks.  I'm not sure it's open source, though.

Comment: This looks like what the OP wants ("The Radar is optimized for use outdoors", but then by the nature of Geo-location, everything is).  "ApproachMe® is a live, Self-Guiding Radar™ (SGR) app that makes it easy, private and fun to find family & friends in crowds such as in shopping malls, festivals, concerts, sporting events, parking lots, amusement parks, or wherever maps are impractical or nonexistent."  "You can send a request to a family member or a friend. Once they accept, you will be able to use the live, Self-Guiding Radar to find each other even if everyone is moving."  This looks good

Comment: oops, I was sure that this is match & wanted to recommend it be accepted as the answer, BUT, it doesn't seem to meet "Show both our positions on a map, ideally using local OsmAnd maps rather than downloading maps via the network". Otoh, that was only a bonus feature, so this might still be acceptable. Welcome abroad, @MoeHoward and thanks for the good input.